# How Do Java Apps Close in Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, api, memory-leaks

I have been writing a Java program to run in Mac OS X. One thing that's been confusing me, however, is that I've seen [some people saying](http://nakkaya.com/2009/04/19/java-osx-integration/) that if the user quits the app from the menu bar, the app does not close properly- it will not clean up properly and I have to implement a separate close method for it. However, I've also read that Java for Mac had some large changes it in 2010. When I look at the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/JavaSE6_AppleExtensionsRef/api/com/apple/eawt/Application.html#setQuitStrategy%28com.apple.eawt.QuitStrategy%29), it seems as if the default close action is now calling SYSTEM_EXIT_0. Does this mean that it calls System.exit(0)? Does this solve the cleanup problem? I'm kind of confused because of all the changes to the API and all the deprecations that occurred when Apple stopped controlling Java for Mac.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to see whether or not the program is cleaning up correctly, but I have looked at Activity Monitor, and I have seen that my program no longer shows up there when I close it. I would like to know if I'm not writing something correctly and causing a memory leak.

Comment: You could use something like a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))to check to see if the JVM is been exited or not